# Angular $resource POSTing entire object, not just properties passed to it

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm using Angular's $resource to interface with an API, and creating custom methods on that resource. One of these methods is a POST, and when I attempt to use it, it's sending the entire resource, not just the properties I'm attempting to post to the API. I don't think this is the intended behavior of the $resource service, but then, I might be missing something.

Here's the code:

The service:

```
angular.module('adminApp')
  .factory('Framework', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/frameworks/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
      'update': {
        method: 'PUT'
      },
      'getRequiredLicenses': {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/frameworks/:id/required_licenses',
        isArray: true
      },
      'addRequiredLicenses': {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/frameworks/:id/required_licenses'
      },
      'removeRequiredLicense': {
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: '/api/frameworks/:id/required_licenses/:license_id'
      }
    });
  });
```

Where I'm calling it:

```
scope.addLicensesToFramework = function() {
  scope.framework.$addRequiredLicenses(null, {
    required_licenses: Object.keys(scope.selectedLicenses) // returns an array of ints
  });
}
```

(Note that this is in a directive. `scope.framework` is the instance of the framework resource)

When this request is sent, here's what's being included in the payload:

[image]

My intention is to only pass `{'required_licenses': [12345,1236]}` in the payload, and I can't seem to figure out why it's sending the entire resource as the body. (It's, in fact, not sending this at all, only the original resource)

Any insight would be really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like this:

```
scope.addLicensesToFramework = function() {
  scope.framework.$addRequiredLicenses({
    required_licenses: Object.keys(scope.selectedLicenses),
    id: 1234
  }, function(resp){ console.log(resp) });
}
```

Also notice that I included the id in the parameters object.. you'll probably need that.